# Matcher.find() return false android

Tags: java, android, pattern-matching

I am trying to get the `softwareVersion` from below html code.

```
<div class="title">Current Version</div> <div class="content" itemprop="softwareVersion"> 1.1.3  </div> </div> <div class="meta-info"> <div class="title">Requires Android</div> <div class="content" itemprop="operatingSystems">     2.2 and up   </div> </div>
```

i used the below code for that

```
String Html = GetHtml("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+ AppID)
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("softwareVersion\">[^<]*</dd");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(Html);
matcher.find();

String GetHtml(String url1) 
    {
        String str = "";
        try 
        {
            URL url = new URL(url1);
            URLConnection spoof = url.openConnection();
            spoof.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0; H010818)");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    spoof.getInputStream()));
            String strLine = "";
            // Loop through every line in the source
            while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                str = str + strLine;
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
        }
        return str;
    }
```

but matcher always return false. I think the i have problem in pattern can anyone pleas help me
Thanks

Comment: use a HTML parser like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Comment: how ? I dont know about it. the below code has pattern problem i am not much aware about pattern.

Comment: Read up using the link above.

Comment: I read it sir but I want to do this using pattern not external parser sorry sir.

Comment: Can you try printing out the Html string to make sure it's what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by somebody else, I would usually use an html parser for extracting stuff from html. However, in your case where you're just pulling a single bit of information out of a string I can see why you want to use a regex.

What you need to do is something like this - the issue with your regex was an extra `d`. Also if you enclose the bit you care about in parenthesis you can grab it using `.group`.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class R {

  public static void main(String[] args){
     String Html = "<div class=\"title\">Current Version</div> <div class=\"content\" itemprop=\"softwareVersion\"> 1.1.3  </div> </div> <div class=\"meta-info\"> <div class=\"title\">Requires Android</div> <div class=\"content\" itemprop=\"operatingSystems\">     2.2 and up   </div> </div>";

     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("softwareVersion\">([^<]*)</d");
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(Html);
     System.out.println(matcher.find());
     System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
  }
}
```

Comment: When I run this code I get `true` and then `1.1.3`. How are you running it?